# powercfg in java program no error no output

Tags: java

powercfg in java program no error no output, when i run it does not shows any output

```
 import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ip{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
try{
String inputLine;
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=r.exec("cmd.exe /c powercfg/batteryreport");
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            //pingResult += inputLine;
        }
}
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
}
}
}
```

Comment: May be `inputLine` is null  . Have you checked for it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because at least on Windows 7, if you try to run powercfg/batteryreport from cmd, you will get
"Invalid Parameters -- try "/?" for help", if you are NOT on laptop. To see this message from Java you should attach p.getErrorStream()

Try 'powercfg -energy', for example

Comment: Again, are you on laptop? Did you try to use powercfg in cmd outside of Java program or attached errorStream?

Comment: Please attach the error stream and post here the result. Perhaps, you need admin rights to run powercfg